# How to name the docked figure window after using the set command in MATLAB 2019b

Tags: matlab, set, figure

After using the set command in matlab 2019b to dock the figures in a separate window:

```
set(0,'DefaultFigureWindowStyle','docked')
```

The docked window has the following name:

*Figures: Figure 46: Mag Sim - Rotation Period*

as can be seen in the following printscreen for my 46th figure:

[image: Print Screen]

I would like to change the name of this window from "Figures" to something else so it will look like:

*My Defined Name*: Figure 46: Mag Sim - Rotation Period

Comment: I want to change the word “Figures” to a name of my choice.

Comment: This is not about `figure` object. You would to have to find the undocumented property of the docker object. An easier solution is to use this [setFigDockGroup](https://mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/16650-setfigdockgroup) from the file exchange. It will allow you to create your own docking group and name them at will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the same command as you would have when creating the window:

```
set(gcf,'Name','Window 1')
```

´gcf´ is the *generic current figure* hande aka. *get current figure* handle. If you want to name it right when creating the figure, use:

```
figure('Name','Window 2')
```

Comment: What you proposed names the first figure, not the main docked window...

Comment: Sorry, your screenshot is quite misleading. However, than the answer is **this can't be done**. You want to change the code of the Matlab IDE. In fact, it is the same as if you would want to change the title *Command Window* to *Dr. Evil's sandbox*...

Comment: I always though it was *get current figure*, but I have no proof of why!

Comment: Because it's short for `get(0,'CurrentFigure')`.

Comment: @AnderBiguri this can actually be. I have no idea why this stuck in my mind. A quick googleing didn't brought up an answer. Let me know if you find something =)